# Apply css to a child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following

```
<div class="selects">
    <div class="icon fluid select"> 
        <i ng-class="{'large svg guests icon':rooms==2, 'large svg guest icon':rooms==1}" class="large svg icon guests"></i>
        <label ng-click="closeCalendar()" class="">
            <select ng-model="rooms" name="rooms" class="fluid ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-dirty" focus-parent="" required="">
                <option value="1">Einzelzimmer</option>
                <option value="2">Doppelzimmer</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to apply some css to i, so I wrote:

```
.select > i {
    background-color:black;
}
```

but it doesn't change, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? http://jsfiddle.net/64T37/

Comment: Your code appears to be correct as @BarbaraLaird has said unless we are mis understand your question? Are you sure the rest of your code (outside of what you have posted) is correct

Comment: Could the problem have been that <i> didn't have anything within it, so it had no size?  I added content for my example.

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my browser. It works now.
I used the first-child pseudo element to target the first child "i" in this case. Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

```
    .select:first-child {
     background-color:black;

}
```

Comment: Your CSS doesn't match what you said. Might be because you've mistakenly called `:first-child` a pseudo-element - it's not a pseudo-element, it's a pseudo-class, which means it looks at the same element, in this case `.select`.